# Secretary problem: Help with the derivation of the solution

Tags: probability

The derivation is on the wiki page:  [image: derivation]
https://ibb.co/mHuAin

I do  not understand how to get the sum into the integral: here are my steps.

$P\left( r\right) =\dfrac {r-1}{n}\sum ^{n}_{i=r}\dfrac {1}{i-1}$

$P\left( r\right) =\dfrac {r-1}{n}\sum ^{n}_{i=r-1}\dfrac {1}{i}$

$$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }P\left( r\right) =\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac {r-1}{n}{\displaystyle\int} ^{n}_{r-1}\frac {1}{i}di=\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac {r-1}{n}{\displaystyle\int}^{1}_{\frac {r-1}{n}}\dfrac {1}{t}dt$$

where $t = i/n$.

Let $x=\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac {r-1}{n}$.

So are these steps incorrect as I have $P\left( x\right) =x{\displaystyle\int}^{1}_{x}\frac {1}{t}dt=-x\ln \left( x\right) $ for a different $x$.

Answer (score 1):

It is simpler to use the approximation
$$\frac 11+\frac 12+\dots+\frac 1n\approx \ln n\ .$$
The difference converges to a constant, [the Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant). So we have "for big $r,n$" the "better" approximation
$$ \sum_{r\le k\le n}\frac 1k \approx \ln n-\ln(r-1)=\ln \frac n{r-1}\ . $$
(There is one more term in one of the posted sums, well...)